# use the return value of function in protactor

Tags: promise, return, protractor

How Do I user the row value to pass UI Input?
I am trying to retrieve data from DB and using in UI. By using following, getting row but want make function and function return value will be use as input
Please need help on this.

```js
function (done) {
        //var query= "SELECT name FROM partstatus where rand() limit 1";
        var query = "select part from parttable order by RAND() limit 1;"
        conn.result(query).then(function(rows){
            // This function get called, when success
            console.log("Looks:",rows);
            done();
        },function(error){
            // This function get called, when error
            console.log(error);
            done.fail(error);

        });        
    }
```

Comment: pass `rows` to your `done` callback.

Comment: Thank for reply. I got that data but now How call this function in other fun where I am passing the value in UI?  this.dbPartdata = function(){
            var ret = [];
            var query = 
            conn.result(query).then(function(rows){
            // This function get called, when success
                ret = JSON.stringify(rows);
                console.log("Looks:",ret);
                return ret;
            });
    };

Comment: this.dbpart = function(){ } How call this function in this.searchPart = function(){}

Comment: the code in the comment seems totally unrelated to the code in the question

Comment: @Jaromanda X , That code which I shared, resolved my problem. But now Data coming in dbpart variable and want use this in searchPart() function which is in page object Model.var part(){this.dbdata(){}; this.searchPart(){ Need to call dbdata()}}. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first select the input element of your HTML and then send the text that you fetch from database, using something like:

`element(by.model('greeting')).sendKeys('Hello, E2E Tests');`

This will get the HTML element bound to model 'greeting' and then put the text passed to sendkeys() to the HTML element.